# Can the incremental compiler in sbt be turned off for CI builds?

Tags: scala, sbt, incremental-build

While looking for a way to improve compile times on our build server, I came across this issue about [overhead added by the incremental compiler](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1078).  Since our build server checks out a fresh copy of the source and builds from scratch each time, it would be nice to be able to disable the incremental compiler completely and not have to pay for something that will not be used.  Is this possible?

Comment: If you delete the buildfolder before each build there will be no incremental compilation.

Comment: @AndreasNeumann - that won't eliminate the overhead mentioned in the issue. I do not want to incur the cost of extracting the public API and dependency information from the source code. The collection of this information is what I want to eliminate as it will never be used and could allow builds to speed up by 15-20%.

Comment: Ok, deleted the faulty answer. I pretty much think it's not possible, yet.

Comment: Hmm, actually, it appears you may need to wait for some upcoming experiments with incremental compilation.  Right now we don't provide a means of generating an "Analysis" object without the incremental compiler, and you need that for the rest of some sbt features to work (like finding main classes, etc.)

You should open a ticket (feature request) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grzegorz says in [#1078](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1078#issuecomment-41381276):

> The original numbers I got back in January were wrong because I was using hacked version of incremental compiler for benchmarks. I gathered more numbers using sbt 0.13.2 and the overhead of incremental compiler [snip] As you can see, for all projects apart from Scala itself, the overhead is below 10%.

So the case was closed as invalid. Related, [Ability to disable incremental compiler for CI builds](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1282) was closed as won't-fix.

> Is this possible?

The here answer is, no (we might be open to pull reqs).

Comment: That's a bit unfortunate.  We have a project that is rather large and the amount of time to compile it on our CI agents can be rather long (15+ minutes).  With lots of branches being built, even a small improvement of 5-10% could be worthwhile for us.